# Parsing an XML file using mulesoft

Tags: file, parsing, mule

I am trying to parse an Simple XMl file read from disk and convert that to JSON and store it back to a file using Mulesoft.

This is how the mule flow.xml looks like

```
<file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File1" outputPattern="sample1.txt" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="datatranformerFlow">
         <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Madhu"   name="sample.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
         <file:file-to-string-transformer mimeType="application/xml" doc:name="File to String"/>
         <splitter expression="#[xpath3('/Names/Name')]" doc:name="Splitter"/>
         <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
         <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Madhu\GV dev documents\WD files" connector-ref="File1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
     </flow>
```

The sample xml file that i am trying to parse looks like

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <title>bnbnbha</title>
        <firstname>aa</firstname>
        <lastname>aaa</lastname>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <title>bjkjkjk</title>
        <firstname>bb</firstname>
        <lastname>bbb</lastname>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <title>hjhjhc</title>
        <firstname>cc</firstname>
        <lastname>ccc</lastname>
    </Name> 
    <Name>
        <title>djkjkj</title>
        <firstname>dd</firstname>
        <lastname>ddd</lastname>
    </Name> 
</Names>
```

When i run the mule project, i am getting an exception

INFO  2016-07-29 11:56:25,287 [[datatranformer].File.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Madhu\sample.xml
INFO  2016-07-29 11:56:26,193 [[datatranformer].datatranformerFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.routing.ExpressionSplitter: The expression does not evaluate to a type that can be split: java.lang.String
ERROR:  'Unexpected character 'b' (code 98) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3]'
ERROR 2016-07-29 11:56:26,272 [[datatranformer].datatranformerFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy:

---

Message               : com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character 'b' (code 98) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException)
Payload               : 
        bnbnbha
        aa
        aaa

Is there something i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If your purpose is only reading an XML file, convert it to JSON, and store it to file (without further process) then remove the *File to String* transformer and the *Splitter* flow control.

So you configuration become like this:

```
<flow name="datatranformerFlow">
     <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Madhu" name="sample.xml" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" connector-ref="File"/>
     <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
     <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Madhu\GV dev documents\WD files" connector-ref="File1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
 </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use #[xpath3('/Names')]

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the splitter expression, as you have mentioned you just want to convert this file into csv, please check the below flow:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json"
 xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
 xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd">
  <file:connector name="File" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:connector name="File1" outputPattern="sample1.txt" autoDelete="false" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
    <flow name="datatranformerFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\madhu" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <file:file-to-string-transformer doc:name="File to String"/>
        <json:xml-to-json-transformer mimeType="application/json" doc:name="XML to JSON"/>
        <logger message="payload--&gt; #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
     <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Madhu\GV dev documents\WD files" connector-ref="File1" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
     </flow>
</mule>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing it

1. you can use XPath
2. you can do it by transform message component
3. you can do it by JSON to XML converter